# How to move versions of files between branches

Tags: mercurial

I am using Mercurial. I have a file `X` that has two versions in two different branches. I have a version in the `R1` branch and an updated version with bugfixes in the `R0` branch. I have merged the fixes from `R0` into `R1`, but somehow file X was not properly merged.

I now want to move the version of `X` that is in my `R0` branch into the `R1` branch.

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm assuming you want to move just a single file, and not negate the entire `R1` branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update to the target branch, revert the file to the the revision of the other branch, then commit.

```
hg update R1
hg revert -r R0 X
hg commit
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider [graft](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/graft) as well (NOTE: I don't know enough about the state of your repository after the merges, but `graft` has helped me when I had to transfer changesets from one branch to another)